# Why is the touchstart event not firing in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, touchstart

I am trying to use the `touchstart` event to detect touches in a web application. It's working fine in Chrome, but in Firefox 36.0.1 (Desktop version) on Windows 8.1, the event is not fired at all.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? A minimal working example can be found [here](http://extern.fefrei.de/20150315/mwe.html).

Comment: You need to enable them, in desktop firefox, go to about:config and enable them. On Firefox Mobile they are enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Because according to [the Mozilla reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events) that event has been disabled in Firefox since version 24. See more information in [this bug ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888304).

I think this event hasn't yet been properly formalized in the standard. You might want to consider using other events like mousedown / mouseup

Comment: Nope, touch events should work properly on FF Mobile. They are behind the flags since version 24 on Desktop, but on FF Mobile they should work properly.

Comment: The context of my answer (and the question I perceive) is Firefox on desktop. Maybe OP should re-clarify this

Comment: I'm talking about desktop touch devices running the desktop version of Firefox. Is there any other way to detect a touch?

Comment: No, you can't because they are off by default. There is no way to detect. After some bugs are fixed in FF they will be enabled by default again.
You can use something like 'ontouchstart' in window but it will always return false.